# Runnable Jar File showing nothing

Tags: java, image, runnable

I am having a problem that when I create a runnable jar file that nothing is loading on the screen. After some research, I believe the problem is to do with how I am loading the images but I am not sure of the solution to fix that.

The code below is just a snippet of how I load the images.

Thank you~

```
public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable {
public Thread thread = new Thread(this); 

public static Image[] tileset_ground = new Image[100]; 
public static Image[] tileset_air = new Image[100]; 
public static Image[] tileset_res = new Image[100];
public static Image[] tileset_mob = new Image[100]; 
public static Image[] tileset_characters = new Image[10];

public static int myWidth, myHeight; 
public static int coinage, health;
public static int randomMob = 0;
public static int level = 1, maxLevel = 5;
public static int killed = 0;
public static int killsToWin = 0; 
public static int winTime = 4000, winFrame = 0;
public int mobsCreated = 0; 

public static boolean isFirst = true;
public static boolean isDebug = false;
public static boolean isWin = false;
public static boolean isMainMenu = true;
public static boolean exit = false;

public static boolean clicked = false;

public static Point mse = new Point(0,0); 

public static Room room; 
public static Save save;
public static Store store; 
public static MainMenu mainMenu;

public static Mob[] mobs = new Mob[100]; 


public Screen(Frame frame) {
    frame.addMouseListener(new KeyHandle());
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new KeyHandle());
    thread.start(); 
}

public void hasWon(){
    if(killsToWin == killed){
        isWin = true;
        killed = 0;
        coinage = 10;
    }
}

public void define() {
    room = new Room(); 
    save = new Save(); 
    store = new Store(); 
    coinage = Values.coinage;
    health = Values.health;


    for(int i =0; i<tileset_ground.length; i++) {
        tileset_ground[i] = new ImageIcon("res/tileset_ground.png").getImage(); 
        tileset_ground[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_ground[i].getSource(), new CropImageFilter(0,26*i,26,26)));
    }

    for(int i =0; i<tileset_air.length; i++) {
        tileset_air[i] = new ImageIcon("res/tileset_air.png").getImage(); 
        tileset_air[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_air[i].getSource(), new CropImageFilter(0,26*i,26,26)));
    }

    tileset_res[0] = new ImageIcon("res/cell.png").getImage();
    tileset_res[1] = new ImageIcon("res/coin.png").getImage();
    tileset_res[2] = new ImageIcon("res/heart.png").getImage(); 
    tileset_res[3] = new ImageIcon("res/startbutton.png").getImage();
    tileset_res[4] = new ImageIcon("res/quitbutton.png").getImage();
    tileset_res[5] = new ImageIcon("res/cellchar.png").getImage();
    tileset_res[6] = new ImageIcon("res/mainmenu.png").getImage();


    tileset_mob[0] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelcody.png").getImage(); 
    tileset_mob[1] = new ImageIcon("res/floatingmob1.png").getImage();
    tileset_mob[10] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelraghev.png").getImage();

    tileset_characters[1] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelcody.png").getImage();
    tileset_characters[2] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelraghev.png").getImage();
    tileset_characters[4] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelbio.png").getImage();
    tileset_characters[3] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelpeter.png").getImage();
    tileset_characters[5] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelkat.png").getImage();
    tileset_characters[7] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelvicky.png").getImage();
    tileset_characters[6] = new ImageIcon("res/pixelkyle.png").getImage();
```

Comment: are your files included inside the jar or in an external directory named *res*? If they are in your jar file please give a tree view of your internal packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to an exception being thrown on startup.

In order to load from a .jar, you must modify your code slightly. For your ImageIcon constructors, you need to change them.

```
ImageIcon whatever = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("path to image")));
```

Be sure to import ImageIO:
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

However, due to the fact that you are using arrays of Images, I would recommend simply using ImageIO.read() without messing with using ImageIcons. Also, in my experience, I have always had to preface the path to the image with an additional "/".

This should work.

One way I try to see if something is going wrong is put a try...catch around the entire program and catch Exception. I then print the stack trace to a file.

```
try {
...
}catch(Exception e){
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("trace.txt");
e.printStackTrace(writer);
writer.close();}
```

Comment: tileset_res[6] = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/mainmenu.png"))); 
 So I tried this but what is happening is that its trying to convert between an ImageIcon and a Image

Comment: There should be a constructor for ImageIcon that takes an Image as its only parameter.

Comment: For example, I have some code that says:          Image title = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/title.png")); ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(title);

Comment: Not sure what to say, it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageIcon to Image"

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I overlooked the Object type in the Array you are using. You initialized your arrays as Image[] arrays, and are now trying to put ImageIcons into them. That is another issue. So I would remove all references to ImageIcons and just create them later. More versatile that way (you can do what you want with the images later (for example, putting them in ImageIcons))

Comment: Or at least include the .getImage() at the end.

Comment: So just write it as  
tileset_res[6] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/mainmemnu.png")); ?

Comment: That should work. Try that, but if it gives you a FileNotFoundException, try an additional slash in front of "res" so it will read tileset_res[6] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/mainmemnu.png"));     I would normally have to do that, but it might work without the additional slash for you.

Comment: I tried tileset_res[6] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/mainmenu.png")).getImage(); but that just gives me an error "The method getImage() is undefined for the type BufferedImage" even without the getImage(); I am still getting errors. Sigh, so difficult just to get an image to render.

Comment: So, ImageIO.read(URL u) returns a Buffered Image, which extends Image. For all intents and purposes, it should work to put it into an array of Images. ImageIO.read() has a checked exception, so make sure you throws or catch it. What exactly is the error you are getting. Assuming your code is anything like how I would do it, it would be along the lines of: try{ tileset_res[6] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/mainmenu.png"));  } catch(IOException ex){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem loading image!"); //tileset_res[6] = new BufferedImage();}

Comment: Alright, so I got it to go without a syntax error but now it is causing me to have a NPE.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you getting the NPE only when jarred, or in the IDE as well? One way you could go about finding the cause of the Null Pointer would be to write the stack trace to a file. I am editing my main post to show how to do this. If you want me to try fiddling around with your code, let me know and I'd be happy to help you debug. Images were always one very annoying part of GUI development for me.

Comment: That be great, which is the easiest way to send you me code? I am install the helios to see if that may fix the problem.

Comment: Just email me at thikanstudio@gmail.com. I'll take a look at it. Images might be helpful too, just so I can know if it's actually working. Hope I can help!

Comment: Sent, hopefully you received it.

Comment: Got it and fixed it, composing email (I'm not sure how closely your setup resembles mine so I'm just talking about what I did as opposed to just sending you back everything)

Comment: Thank you again, looking forward to see how you fixed the problem.